# What is the difference between "Send on Page Submit" and "Query Only" in an APEX Item?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

In Oracle Apex, all items have the Source > Query Only attribute but display only items also have the attribute "Send on Page Submit". I have found a somewhat official explanation of the Query Only attribute [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/forms-in-apex-191-more-power,-more-flexibility) but did not come across anything explaining in detail what "Send on Page Submit" does. What is the difference between these two attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about *details*, but - while in Apex, navigate to (any) property and switch to "Help" tab which then says

> Send On Page Submit 
> Specify whether the current item value should be sent when the page is submitted.

Or, in *official* [documentation ("About Item Types")](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/htmdb/about-item-types.html#GUID-81BF829A-B26C-484D-A321-6A3F47C9192B).

---

When do we use it? For example, if displaying a primary key value (which is "automatically generated"), we don't want users to mess it up. If that property is set to OFF, primary key value won't be set into the database and you'll get ORA-01400.

Another usage is when we're setting a value without violating session state protection.

Maybe there are other situations, but I either haven't seen them or I've forgotten about them.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. From the help tab, I was able to see that the Query Only property only affects DML operations with the Interactive Grid. So they are similar, but Send On Page Submit is for form submission whereas Query Only seems to be for Interactive Grid.